# Is 172.20.0.2/24 an ip address or subnet?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, ip-address, subnets

Can we also assign a subnet to a computer as an ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Literarily, "172.20.0.2/24" is: An ip address 172.20.0.2 with prefix length 24 bits.

We use "172.20.0.0/24" as its prefix. ("Subnet" is an obsoleted concept, we should now use "prefix")

You can assign addresses to a "network interface device of your computer", not "your computer".

And, NO, you can't assign a subnet to any network interface device.